# Laravel Search Sort filter by Button click

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Its Possible to make an Search filter with an Button click?

Thats what i have try and i think its work in this way:

I have in the Menu one Search Input Field and after i search an Word i see the results + the Sortby Button.

Route for Search:

```
Route::any ( '/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    if($q != ""){
    $products = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->paginate (200)->setPath ( '' );
    $pagination = $products->appends ( array (
                'q' => Input::get ( 'q' ) 
        ) );




    if (count ( $products ) > 0)
        return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
    }






$s = Input::get ( 's' );
    if($s != ""){
    $products = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%' )->paginate (200)->setPath ( '' );
    $pagination = $products->appends ( array (
                's' => Input::get ( 's' ) 
        ) );




    if (count ( $products ) > 0)
        return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
    }


        return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'We dont found any Products with your search query. Please try again !' );
} );
```

The `$s` is what i have added now to try the Button:

```
$s = Input::get ( 's' );
        if($s != ""){
        $products = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%' )->paginate (200)->setPath ( '' );
        $pagination = $products->appends ( array (
                    's' => Input::get ( 's' ) 
            ) );




        if (count ( $products ) > 0)
            return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
        }
```

My `$s` Button:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  Choose your favorite subject:
  <button name="q" type="submit" value="{{ $query }}{{ $s }}">HTML</button>
</form>
```

The value from the Button is default only `value="{{ $query }}"`

I have added also `{{ $s }}` to it but first i must change the `$s` Route of Course later that i can Products sortby for example `created_at`.

I want an Url like this: `/search?q=mysearchword&s=createdat`

Possible?

If yes how i can add the `&` after `q=mysearchword` and what i must write in my Route instead of `$s = Input::get ( 's' );` because its not an input.

Many Thanks!

Comment: This [http://justlaravel.com/search-functionality-laravel/](http://justlaravel.com/search-functionality-laravel/) may help

Comment: Thanks buts its only Search no sortby. The Search function i have already.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass two parameters like that.

Instead, use an input hidden with the value you want to pass.
Also, you should do it as well for the `$query` var.

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  Choose your favorite subject:
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="{{ $s }}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ $query  }}" />
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

> If yes how i can add the & after q=mysearchword and what i must write in my Route instead of $s = Input::get ( 's' ); because its not an input.

The way i showed you, you can get the `$s` var using `Input::get('s')` because it is now an input

Another way to do it, and following how you have your html you can add a delimiter in between your `$query` and `$s` var and explode the result in php:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  Choose your favorite subject:
  <button name="q" type="submit" value="{{ $query }}&{{ $s }}">HTML</button>
</form>
```

And php:

```
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );
$data = explode('&', $q);
$query = $data[0];
$s = $data[1];
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

first of all, use a controller to avoid this spaghetti code inside your route:

1. eg., modify your route to `Route::any ( '/search', ['as'=> ‘find’, 'uses' => 'SearchController@find’]);`
2. create SearchController.php, and add `find` method there

   ```
       public function find(Request $request){

           $input = $request->all();
           $q = $input[‘q’];
           $s = $input[‘s’];
           /*continue here your code*/
           }
   ```
3. Then change your html to send `q` and `s` from your form:

```html
    <form action="/search" method="get">
      Choose your favorite subject:
     <input id=“q” name=“q” type="hidden" value="{{ $query}}">
     <input id=“s” name=“s” type="hidden" value="{{ $s }}">
      <button name=“button” type="submit">HTML</button>
    </form>
```